# Find correlation between *values* in columns

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Consider a dataset where each row is a basket of 3 fruits.

```
library(data.table)
baskets <- data.table(fruit_1 = c('orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear')
                      ,fruit_2 = c('apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi')
                      ,fruit_3 = c('pear', 'kiwi', 'blueberry', 'blueberry'))
```

What would be an efficient way to calculate correlations between different fruits? In other words, how often different fruits appear in the same basket/row together? I'm trying to get the pairwise correlation for every pair of 2 fruits (for example, "apples and pears", "apples and kiwis", etc.).

The best approach I can think of now is to make indicator variables/binary columns for each fruit and then do the correlation of those. Is there a better way than that, computationally or otherwise?

**EDIT: I updated this part to show a table that looks like my desired result. It would probably want "agreement/disagreement score" or something instead of the correlation, but you get the idea.**

```
baskets$apple = 0
baskets[fruit_1=='apple']$apple = 1
baskets[fruit_2=='apple']$apple = 1
baskets[fruit_3=='apple']$apple = 1

baskets$pear = 0
baskets[fruit_1=='pear']$pear = 1
baskets[fruit_2=='pear']$pear = 1
baskets[fruit_3=='pear']$pear = 1

baskets$kiwi = 0
baskets[fruit_1=='kiwi']$kiwi = 1
baskets[fruit_2=='kiwi']$kiwi = 1
baskets[fruit_3=='kiwi']$kiwi = 1

#looking for a table like this, but with every combination of fruit and imagining thousands of rows
desired_result = data.frame(fruit_1 = c('apple', 'pear', 'kiwi'),
                            fruit_2 = c('pear', 'kiwi', 'apple'),
                            similarity = c(cor(baskets$apple, baskets$pear),
                                           cor(baskets$pear, baskets$kiwi),
                                           cor(baskets$kiwi, baskets$apple)
                                           )
                            )
```

This feels like an okay solution, but not a great one. So I wanted to see what better options there are. Data.table is highly preferable because I'm much better at that but I'm open to whatever.

Comment: The problem you're describing is usually called affinity analysis or market basket analysis. There are many approaches, and this isn't the venue to try and find a "best" solution. This [r-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/04/market-basket-analysis-in-r/) is a nice vignette style presentation of one way to get started.

Comment: Do you essentially want a concordance table - `crossprod(table(data.frame(basket=seq_len(nrow(baskets)), fruit=unlist(baskets))))` or something similar?

Comment: Correlation with two sets of binary data is essentially just agreement/disagreement proportion, particularly if it's seemingly unordered like your example, so just tabulate it and be done with it (e.g. - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222924/correlation-between-two-binary-variables )

Comment: Thanks guys! @thelatemail thanks for that tip, agreement porportion seems like what i want. I don't necessarily know from there though what hte most efficient way is to find that for each combination of fruits.

I'll try that crossprodtable step tomorrow when i wake up and report back.

Comment: @Seth I glanced through the blog post and will see if I can figure out applying it a bit tomorrow as well. Now I understand much better the words I need to search for :).

Comment: @thelatemail that crossprod is very similar to what I'd like, and using that we could calculate whatever metric. 

Do you know an easy way to do that but have it in a more vertical format? I edited my question to show better the format that I'd be looking for.

Comment: @Seth the blog post is definitely interesting, but for now its solutions are more complicated than what I'm looking for. Also, it's assuming that we already have the binary variables that in my data I don't have (I could start by trying to make them as I indicated, though).

Comment: You should distinguish "correlation" from "cooccurrence", what are definitely 2 different things. Which is the one you really want in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cor` along with `as.data.frame.table`, e.g.,

```
subset(
    as.data.frame.table(
        cor(table(row(baskets), unlist(baskets))),
        responseName = "similarity",
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    ),
    Var1 < Var2
)
```

and you will obtain

```
        Var1      Var2 similarity
6      apple blueberry -0.5773503
11     apple      kiwi -0.3333333
12 blueberry      kiwi  0.5773503
16     apple    orange  0.3333333
17 blueberry    orange -0.5773503
18      kiwi    orange -1.0000000
21     apple      pear -0.3333333
22 blueberry      pear -0.5773503
23      kiwi      pear -0.3333333
24    orange      pear  0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a co-occurrence table, generated using `crossprod`, might be helpful, to get the counts of how often values appear, and appear together.

```
out <- crossprod(table(
    data.frame(basket=seq_len(nrow(baskets)), fruit=unlist(baskets))
))
out
#           fruit
#fruit       apple blueberry kiwi orange pear
#  apple         3         1    2      1    2
#  blueberry     1         2    2      0    1
#  kiwi          2         2    3      0    2
#  orange        1         0    0      1    1
#  pear          2         1    2      1    3
```

The `diag`onal will be the raw frequency data:

```
diag(out)
#    apple blueberry      kiwi    orange      pear 
#        3         2         3         1         3
```

You can get it in a long form too if you like:

```
as.data.frame.table(out)[lower.tri(out),]
#       fruit   fruit.1 Freq
#2  blueberry     apple    1
#3       kiwi     apple    2
#4     orange     apple    1
#5       pear     apple    2
#8       kiwi blueberry    2
#9     orange blueberry    0
#10      pear blueberry    1
#14    orange      kiwi    0
#15      pear      kiwi    2
#20      pear    orange    1
```

And if you want to include the `diag`onal, you can do so:

```
as.data.frame.table(out)[lower.tri(out, diag=TRUE),]
#       fruit   fruit.1 Freq
#1      apple     apple    3
#2  blueberry     apple    1
#...
```